# Metadata API without SOAP

Tags: apex, metadata-api, metadata, rest, custom-metadata

I am new in the Metadata APIs of Salesforce world, but they look interesting.

I want to know if I can use Metadata APIs or basically create custom objects / fields etc. on any org without using SOAP based approach, as I want to create a generic solution.

I already saw this great library by the great Andrew Fawcett (github - afawcett)

https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi

but wanted to know if there is a way which can help me generate a generic way to create metadata without importing anything in my org.

Thanks
Ray

Comment: can u add some context on your use case where you want Metadata API access.. did you try to see if your work can be done with Apex + any other platform feature and then decided Metadata API is the only way ?

Comment: I would like to create a custom code base which when integrated with process builder or any custom page can give admins provision to create Custom Objects or fields in a custom object dynamically. I assume this is only possible using Metadata api

Answer (score 2):

I believe it would have to be a web-service based approach. As far as I know, there aren't native APEX methods for adding new custom objects or fields.

Answer (score 0):

You can create *some* sorts of metadata using the [Tooling Rest Api](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/intro_rest_overview.htm). Custom fields are supported this way, as are record types, workflow rules, and a number of other setup types. Unfortunately, you can't yet create custom *objects* this way yet (custom objects support the rest method GET, with either an ID or a query, but they don't support POST), so you need to use a SOAP-based solution if you need to make entirely new objects (rather than just adding fields to existing ones).